# About Picard's little theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

In the process of showing map $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphic. If we assume $f$ is injective and holomorphic, I want to use the little Picard theorem to illustrate $f$ surjective, but there is a stunk for me that if $$f=e^z: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*}=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$$

How to deal with it? Since  Picard's little theorem supports the map is not just onto $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What does $C^*$ mean?

Comment: @user247327 $\mathbb{C}^{*}=\mathbb{C}$ removes 0.

Comment: You ignore it, since it doesn't satisfy your hypothesis. It is not injective $e^{2\pi i }=e^0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we're trying to show that if $f$ is an injective entire function then $f$ is surjective.

Suppose not; say $f(z)\ne\alpha$ for every $z$. Let $g=f-\alpha$.  Then $g=e^h$ for some entire function $h$. Little Picard shows that $h$ must assume more than one of the values $0,2\pi i, 4\pi i,\dots$; hence $e^h$ is not injective.

Comment: Thanks for your help.